# What am I doing wrong when compiling C code to bare metal (raspberry pi)?

Tags: c, assembly, raspberry-pi

I have spent multiple days trying to figure this out and I just can't. I have some C code. I have made the assembly code for this C program, copy pasted the assembly to someone else's project (that only contains a single assembly file) and assembled that. In these case things work. But if I try to compile from C directly to generate the binaries, it doesn't work. Even though everything else should be identical. This is my C code:

```
 #include <stdint.h>

#define REGISTERS_BASE 0x3F000000
#define MAIL_BASE 0xB880  // Base address for the mailbox registers
// This bit is set in the status register if there is no space to write into the mailbox
#define MAIL_FULL 0x80000000
// This bit is set in the status register if there is nothing to read from the mailbox
#define MAIL_EMPTY 0x40000000

struct Message
{
  uint32_t messageSize;
  uint32_t requestCode;
  uint32_t tagID;
  uint32_t bufferSize;
  uint32_t requestSize;
  uint32_t pinNum;
  uint32_t on_off_switch;
  uint32_t end;
};

struct Message m =
{
  .messageSize = sizeof(struct Message),
  .requestCode =0,
  .tagID = 0x00038041,
  .bufferSize = 8,
  .requestSize =0,
  .pinNum = 130,
  .on_off_switch = 1,
  .end = 0,
};

/** Main function - we'll never return from here */
int _start(void)
{
  uint32_t mailbox = MAIL_BASE + REGISTERS_BASE + 0x18;
  volatile uint32_t status;

  do
  {
    status = *(volatile uint32_t *)(mailbox);
  }
  while((status & 0x80000000));

  *(volatile uint32_t *)(MAIL_BASE + REGISTERS_BASE + 0x20) = ((uint32_t)(&m) & 0xfffffff0) | (uint32_t)(8);

  while(1);
}
```

This is a linker file I copied from the successful method:

```
/*
 * Very simple linker script, combing the text and data sections
 * and putting them starting at address 0x800.
 */
SECTIONS {
  /* Put the code at 0x80000, leaving room for ARM and
   * the stack. It also conforms to the standard expecations.
   */
  .init 0x8000 : {
    *(.init)
  }

  .text : {
    *(.text)
  }

  /* Put the data after the code */
  .data : {
    *(.data)
  }
}
```

And these is how I am compiling and linking everything:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -O0 -march=armv8-a PiTest.c -nostartfiles -o kernel.o
arm-none-eabi-ld kernel.o -o kernel.elf -T kernel.ld
arm-none-eabi-objcopy kernel.elf -O binary kernel.img
```

My target architecture is armv8 since that's what the pi model 3 uses.
I have no idea how the generated assembly works, but the C code directly does not. Please help I am on the verge of madness.

EDIT: The expected behaviour is for the pi's light to turn on. which it does with the first method I described. With the second method the light remains off.

EDIT4: Made some changes to files, deleted previous edits with outdated info to reduce post size

```
  kernel.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .init:

00008000 <_start>:
    8000:   e3a0dd7d    mov sp, #8000   ; 0x1f40
    8004:   eaffffff    b   8008 <kernel_main>

Disassembly of section .text:

00008008 <kernel_main>:
    8008:   e52db004    push    {fp}        ; (str fp, [sp, #-4]!)
    800c:   e28db000    add fp, sp, #0
    8010:   e24dd00c    sub sp, sp, #12
    8014:   e30b3898    movw    r3, #47256  ; 0xb898
    8018:   e3433f00    movt    r3, #16128  ; 0x3f00
    801c:   e50b3008    str r3, [fp, #-8]
    8020:   e51b3008    ldr r3, [fp, #-8]
    8024:   e5933000    ldr r3, [r3]
    8028:   e50b300c    str r3, [fp, #-12]
    802c:   e51b300c    ldr r3, [fp, #-12]
    8030:   e3530000    cmp r3, #0
    8034:   bafffff9    blt 8020 <kernel_main+0x18>
    8038:   e30b38a0    movw    r3, #47264  ; 0xb8a0
    803c:   e3433f00    movt    r3, #16128  ; 0x3f00
    8040:   e3082050    movw    r2, #32848  ; 0x8050
    8044:   e3402001    movt    r2, #1
    8048:   e3c2200f    bic r2, r2, #15
    804c:   e3822008    orr r2, r2, #8
    8050:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
    8054:   eafffffe    b   8054 <kernel_main+0x4c>

Disassembly of section .data:

00008058 <__data_start>:
    8058:   00000020    andeq   r0, r0, r0, lsr #32
    805c:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
    8060:   00038041    andeq   r8, r3, r1, asr #32
    8064:   00000008    andeq   r0, r0, r8
    8068:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
    806c:   00000082    andeq   r0, r0, r2, lsl #1
    8070:   00000001    andeq   r0, r0, r1
    8074:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0

Disassembly of section .ARM.attributes:

00000000 <_stack-0x80021>:
   0:   00002e41    andeq   r2, r0, r1, asr #28
   4:   61656100    cmnvs   r5, r0, lsl #2
   8:   01006962    tsteq   r0, r2, ror #18
   c:   00000024    andeq   r0, r0, r4, lsr #32
  10:   412d3805            ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0x412d3805
  14:   070e0600    streq   r0, [lr, -r0, lsl #12]
  18:   09010841    stmdbeq r1, {r0, r6, fp}
  1c:   14041202    strne   r1, [r4], #-514 ; 0xfffffdfe
  20:   17011501    strne   r1, [r1, -r1, lsl #10]
  24:   1a011803    bne 46038 <__bss_end__+0x3dfc0>
  28:   2a012201    bcs 48834 <__bss_end__+0x407bc>
  2c:   Address 0x000000000000002c is out of bounds.


Disassembly of section .comment:

00000000 <.comment>:
   0:   3a434347    bcc 10d0d24 <_stack+0x1050d03>
   4:   35312820    ldrcc   r2, [r1, #-2080]!   ; 0xfffff7e0
   8:   392e343a    stmdbcc lr!, {r1, r3, r4, r5, sl, ip, sp}
   c:   732b332e            ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0x732b332e
  10:   33326e76    teqcc   r2, #1888   ; 0x760
  14:   37373131            ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0x37373131
  18:   2029312d    eorcs   r3, r9, sp, lsr #2
  1c:   2e392e34    mrccs   14, 1, r2, cr9, cr4, {1}
  20:   30322033    eorscc  r2, r2, r3, lsr r0
  24:   35303531    ldrcc   r3, [r0, #-1329]!   ; 0xfffffacf
  28:   28203932    stmdacs r0!, {r1, r4, r5, r8, fp, ip, sp}
  2c:   72657270    rsbvc   r7, r5, #112, 4
  30:   61656c65    cmnvs   r5, r5, ror #24
  34:   00296573    eoreq   r6, r9, r3, ror r5
```

Comment: “It doesn't work” is not an error description. What exactly happens? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: I added an edit since you are right, that's an important detail. The issue is turning the pi's light on.

Comment: Did you just create a kernel that is meant to be bootable ?

Comment: according to the pi's docuemntation, after including a couple of firmware files into the sd card, the first binary to ever be executed on the pi after the booting process will be kernel.img.

Comment: the entry point is 0x80000 for the pi3 0x8000 for the older ones.

Comment: need the disassembly not the assembly generated.

Comment: the raspberry pi forum on the raspberrypi.org website has a baremetal forum with a pinned topic that has a number of resources for getting you started with bare metal on the pi.  numerous examples although many are for the pi1 which is a little different (leds were easy to get at, boots from a different address in svc mode, etc).

Comment: they now have different names for the image files you can use trying to remember what they are off hand, but kernel.img is the fall back if no others are found

Comment: I have seen those tutorials, but the difference in architecture is a problem when trying to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: there is no difference in architecture, can build for armv4 and run it on all the pis, all that varies for the things you are trying to do initially is the base address for the peripherals which is an easy compile time option.  and the entry point for the pi3

Comment: there is a difference in architecture but you are miles away from caring about that at this point

Comment: the example I provided here at SO is a fully working example with C and assembly, hang on, will post something from my readme on entry points...

Comment: this code definitely wont boot as written...

Comment: if it does it is dumb luck...unless you show us the disassembly to see what else you added to the project to fill in the gaps...

Comment: Thank you for being so patient, I had never worked at such a  low level and this is biting me in the ass quite hard right now. I am doing:

arm-none-eabi-objdump -D -b binary -marm kernel.img

I am neverthelees skeptical of the output, I am not usre if that is correct, if it i s I'll post the dissassembled result. But I think even on that I am making a mistake, since it seems there is not text section, only data, according tot eh output

Comment: objdump -D and the elf file

Comment: Ok this makes sense I'll add it to the post. Thank you so much.

Comment: I see you are trying to blink the led and/or turn it on not do video, sorry.  do you have a uart board an ftdi breakout or one of the usb cables that has female connectors on the end?  need to invest in one if you are serious about this project.   also recommend a reset switch that you need to solder or somehow shove into the run pins.  Even a paperclip will do if you are careful not to short to something else...if you are wanting to write an OS right?

Comment: without these tools, you were wanting to write an OS right?  you will literally be removing and replacing the sd card and the usb cable thousands of times to make minor progress...

Comment: lots of folks just download my very simple bootloader, use that to write your own if you dont like it, then work on your application.  you can use a second raspberry pi both as a development machine as well as use the uart to download to the pi under test.

Comment: Well the best way to learn is by trying, :p

Comment: yeah, see your first line is a push, you have not setup the stack, please use a bootstrap in asm...later you can try to get fancy and come up with a hacky  C solution with inline assembly...

Comment: Also this is part of a class I am taking (the class is a self learning project) So I am not allowed to directly used other people's code, i can look at it and reference it, but I have to write everything myself, so I cannot directly use your code. However where is it so that I can use it for reference? (I am very grateful for all your help btw)

Comment: digging out a pi3, dont think I tried using the mailboxes to blink the led, just use the uart...will see what I see tonight with this...

Comment: use your bootstrap, there really isnt any plagarism to a mov sp,#0x8000; b main or bl main and b .

Comment: you can use -Ttext=0x8000 on the linker command line instead of a linker script, just read the manual for the linker and or the linker script and my extremely trivial example becomes your own as you see it basically comes right from the documentation...

Comment: yours was mov sp,#0x8000 then b main right?  just use that.  two instructions plus the global _start and _start label which is clearly not plagarism as it is the gnu way, cant be avoided, could use .global instead of .globl if it makes you feel better.

Comment: if a fully working example is just going to cause you problems then I wont work on that (one that blinks the led).

Comment: Ok I change things  bit I will update the post and try things out and see if things work

Comment: The led remains off, but I think I have the tools to figure out the problem now

Comment: much better, you dont need the -O0 you can use -O2 if you want...

Comment: The -O0 was a paranoic decision. Since things were not working I hoped that without optimizations the code would be closer to the intended logic. But I guess there is no point to it now,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, cudos to old timer for his patience helping me.
The mistakes were:

Wrong entry point for the program, fixed by creating an assembly file with the label _start to set the stack pointer and using the linker to put the init section at address 0x8000

The compilation line itself was also wrong, it was missing a -c argument

Comment: Self answering is ok, but still: accept an answer. And when you found that other answer helpful, accept that.

Answer (score 1):

```
kernel8.img

12345678
00000800
00080264
00000000
12345678

kernel8-32.img

12345678
00008320
00008224
200001DA
12345678

kernel7.img

12345678
00000700
00008224
200001DA
12345678

kernel.img

12345678
00000000
00008224
200001DA
12345678
```

when I wrote and posted this code this is what I got so if you name your file kernel.img then 0x8000 is your entry point the answer I gave in your other SO question is a complete raspberry pi starting point.  You can simply add your mailbox stuff, although if you are struggling with this I thing the mailbox and video are not where you should start IMO.

if you name the file kernel8.img then the entry point is 0x80000 change the linker script to match.

I have a serial port based bootloader you can use to save on the sd card dance, can get a long way with that then simply use the binary version of what you are creating to write to the flash once your application is working.

EDIT

Okay this is incredibly disgusting and by posting it here maybe that means you cant use it in your classwork...you should really do this right and not use inline assembly for your bootstrap...

so.c

```
asm(
".globl _start\n"
"_start:\n"
"mov sp,#0x8000\n"
"bl centry\n"
"b .\n"
);


unsigned int centry ( void )
{
    return(5);
}
```

build

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -O2 -c so.c -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -Ttext=0x8000 so.o -o so.elf
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D so.elf > so.list
arm-none-eabi-objcopy so.elf -O binary kernel.img
```

examine

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00008000 <_start>:
    8000:   e3a0d902    mov sp, #32768  ; 0x8000
    8004:   eb000000    bl  800c <centry>
    8008:   eafffffe    b   8008 <_start+0x8>

0000800c <centry>:
    800c:   e3a00005    mov r0, #5
    8010:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

A complete raspberry pi C with bootstrap example that will work on any of the flavors of pi (so far as I know they might have changed the GPU bootloader in the last few months but assume the didnt).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things I see wrong here. The most obvious ones are:

- You aren't leaving anything at address 0, so the CPU is left executing blank memory at startup. You need to put something (like a branch instruction!) at `0x0`.
- On ARM Cortex-A, the stack pointer is not initialized at startup. You have to initialize it yourself in `_start` -- which means you will need to write that function in assembly.

Comment: First, I thought that the first addresses in ram where reserved for interrupt branching functions. Second, why is the assembly working? shouldn't I be experiencing this problem for both versions of the code?

Comment: They aren't _precisely_ reserved -- you can relocate the vector table when you set up the NVIC. In any case, though, the first word of the vector table is unused, so you can put an instruction there.

Comment: As to the assembly code, I couldn't say without looking at it. It's possible that it doesn't use the stack, though, which would explain why it works (but will stop working as soon as you try to do anything more complicated).

Comment: I added the assembly code, as you can see it does use the stack pointer, despite the stack pointer not having been initialized. I also did the experiment of making a boot.s assembly file that sets the stack pointer and then branches to main (I renamed the main function to main so that code starts executing at boot.s which now has the _start label)  however the led still doesn't turn on.

Comment: the entry point for baremetal on the pi can vary without a config.txt it is 0x8000 for the pi1 and 0x80000 for the pi3, not sure but think the pi2 is 0x8000.  the bootloader is in the gpu and puts the code at 0x0000 to separate the cores switch to hyp mode (for the quad cores) and then branch to 0x8000 or 0x80000

Comment: if you use config.txt you can have it let your code through, this question is a follow on clearly from a prior question this week or weekend, the OP is just following that.  with the pi3 you clearly do not want to start at 0x0000 yourself if you are not already well versed in the toolchain and bootstrapping, (unless you just borrow code from one of us), you have to isolate the cores into separate code as we sett them light up all at once, and not sure if there are separate reset controls in this chip.

Comment: actually OP is not taking my advice (despite my raspi experience), trying to do this the hard way, so I guess will fail for a while.

Comment: I am going to see if the start position is the source of the error, as it seems that would be the case.

Comment: No effect whatsoever.

Comment: post your disassembly please not the assembly, HUGE difference in debugging this.